Convert a gradle command sequence in the zsh terminal to an alias
The following command builds successfully when I type it in the terminal.
export ENV=test; export ENVFILE=.env.test; cd android && rm -rf .gradle && ./gradlew clean

But I have not been able to figure out how to make an alias which does the same thing. I tried using the same command.
alias part2='export ENV=test;  export ENVFILE=env.test; cd android && rm -rf .gradle && ./gradlew clean'

and I tried replacing the ; with &&
alias part2='export ENV=test &&  export ENVFILE=env.test && cd android && rm -rf .gradle && ./gradlew clean'

If I enter export ENV=test; export ENVFILE=env.test; manually in the terminal then the following alias works.
alias p3='cd android && rm -rf .gradle && ./gradlew clean'

I tried using a function and it did not work either.
oh() {
    echo start
    export ENV=test;
    export ENVFILE=env.test;
    cd android && rm -rf .gradle && ./gradlew clean
    echo end
}

